# apply recursive left join

Tags: recursion, sql-server-2012, left-join

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following problem:

I have the this table (Category):

```
IDCategory| CategoryDesc     | Father
1         | R1               | 0
2         | R1 - ST          | 1
3         | R1 - CT          | 1
4         | R1 - ST - SA     | 2
5         | R1 - ST - CA 10  | 2
6         | R1 - ST - CA 20  | 2
7         | R1 - CT - CA     | 3
8         | R1 - CT - SA     | 3
9         | R2               | 0
10        | R2 ST            | 9
.         
.         
until R9
```

And this one (CategoryDefinition):

```
IDCategory| First| Last
1         | 0    | 300
9         | 301  | 600
.         
.         
.
```

And I'm using the following query because I know there're only 3 levels:

```
SELECT
cat3.IDCategory,
cat.CategoryDesc AS title1,
cat2.CategoryDesc AS title2,
cat3.CategoryDesc AS title3,
catdef.First,
catdef.Last
FROM Category as cat
LEFT JOIN Category AS cat2 ON cat2.Father=cat.IDCategory
LEFT JOIN Category AS cat3 ON cat3.Father=cat2.IDCategory
INNER JOIN CategoryDefinition as catdef on cat.IDCategory = catdef.IDCategory
WHERE cat3.IDCategory = 7
```

Query result:

```
IDCategory| title1 | title2  |title3        |First|Last
    7     | R1     | R1 - CT | R1 - CT - CA |  0  | 300
```

But how can I make this recursive? In the case that in the future could appear new levels (So I don't have to add a new left join for each new level that appears).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want each `title` in its own column? A dynamic pivot of a recursive cte just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @SqlZim what you're saying is to show only title3? Instead of showing all 3 titles?

Comment: @SqlZim I (supposedly) need them separeted because the use will have to select each level. First level 1(R1,R2,R3....), according to level 1 I will show the options for level 2 (ST or CT), and according to level 2 then I will show level 3 ( ST - SA, ST - CA 10, ST - CA 20 or CT - CA, CT - SA).

Comment: Pretty much. I don't think the values for `CategoryDesc` are normalized. If anything they resemble a materialized path because they already include the descriptions of their parents -- actually, they seem like they do, but some of the parents aren't the same as what you would expect from the description. (e.g. I would have expected `4`'s father to be `2`, not `3` because of `R1 - ST`)

Comment: @SqlZim that's because I made a mistake copying the table, you're right 4's father IS 2, my bad. OK, I get the problem with the titles, I'll fix that. But what about the left joins if more levels appears, I don't want to change the code every time....Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: because the inner join against CategoryDesc I make it with the ID of the father a not the leafs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can at least help with the recusive cte of an adjacency list and building a materialized path:

For this table:

```
create table category (IDCategory int primary key,CategoryDesc varchar(32),Father int)
insert into category values 
 (1,'R1',0)
,(2,'ST',1)
,(3,'CT',1)
,(4,'SA',3)
,(5,'SA 10',2)
,(6,'SA 20',2)
,(7,'CA',2)
,(8,'SA',2)
,(9,'R2',0)
,(10,'ST',9)
```

using a recursive cte:

```
;with cte as (
-- anchor elements: where Father = 0
  select 
      IDCategory
    , categoryDesc
    , Father
    , parentName = convert(varchar(32),null)
    , path = convert(varchar(128),categoryDesc)
  from category
  where Father = 0
  -- recursion begins here
  union all 
  select 
      c.IDCategory 
    , c.categoryDesc
    , c.Father
    , parentName = p.categoryDesc
    , path = convert(varchar(128),p.path+' - '+c.categoryDesc)
  from category c
    inner join cte as p on c.Father= p.IDCategory
)
-- we select all the results 
select cte.*
from cte 
order by idCategory
```

returns:

```
+------------+--------------+--------+------------+-----------------+
| IDCategory | categoryDesc | Father | parentName |      path       |
+------------+--------------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|          1 | R1           |      0 | NULL       | R1              |
|          2 | ST           |      1 | R1         | R1 - ST         |
|          3 | CT           |      1 | R1         | R1 - CT         |
|          4 | SA           |      3 | CT         | R1 - CT - SA    |
|          5 | SA 10        |      2 | ST         | R1 - ST - SA 10 |
|          6 | SA 20        |      2 | ST         | R1 - ST - SA 20 |
|          7 | CA           |      2 | ST         | R1 - ST - CA    |
|          8 | SA           |      2 | ST         | R1 - ST - SA    |
|          9 | R2           |      0 | NULL       | R2              |
|         10 | ST           |      9 | R2         | R2 - ST         |
+------------+--------------+--------+------------+-----------------+
```

---

Adding the join to the anchor of the recursive cte:

```
;with cte as (
-- anchor elements: where Father = 0
  select 
      c.IDCategory
    , c.categoryDesc
    , c.Father
    , parentName = convert(varchar(32),null)
    , path = convert(varchar(128),c.categoryDesc)
    , cd.First
    , cd.Last
  from category c
    inner join CategoryDefinition cd
      on c.IdCategory=cd.IdCategory
  where Father = 0
  -- recursion begins here
  union all 
  select 
      c.IDCategory 
    , c.categoryDesc
    , c.Father
    , parentName = p.categoryDesc
    , path = convert(varchar(128),p.path+' - '+c.categoryDesc)
    , p.First
    , p.Last
  from category c
    inner join cte as p on c.Father= p.IDCategory
)
select cte.*
from cte 
--where IdCategory = 7
order by idCategory
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/POSVP81190

returns:

```
+------------+--------------+--------+------------+-----------------+-------+------+
| IDCategory | categoryDesc | Father | parentName |      path       | First | Last |
+------------+--------------+--------+------------+-----------------+-------+------+
|          1 | R1           |      0 | NULL       | R1              |     0 |  300 |
|          2 | ST           |      1 | R1         | R1 - ST         |     0 |  300 |
|          3 | CT           |      1 | R1         | R1 - CT         |     0 |  300 |
|          4 | SA           |      3 | CT         | R1 - CT - SA    |     0 |  300 |
|          5 | SA 10        |      2 | ST         | R1 - ST - SA 10 |     0 |  300 |
|          6 | SA 20        |      2 | ST         | R1 - ST - SA 20 |     0 |  300 |
|          7 | CA           |      2 | ST         | R1 - ST - CA    |     0 |  300 |
|          8 | SA           |      2 | ST         | R1 - ST - SA    |     0 |  300 |
|          9 | R2           |      0 | NULL       | R2              |   301 |  600 |
|         10 | ST           |      9 | R2         | R2 - ST         |   301 |  600 |
+------------+--------------+--------+------------+-----------------+-------+------+
```